# Is my friend insane?

Tags: wordplay, word-problem

My friend is soon going to an asylum. This is devastating. I have known him for years and he's a fine, *sane* man. But he sent me a note and it doesn't make any sense...

Has he really lost his mind or does this note have a meaning behind the madness?

> Eye morning hair
>   Doctor me police
>   Bee ring hmm eye death aw ree
>   Thay kiss

Please, this is urgent. Is there any way I can help him?!?!?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not all the way there, and this might be way off the mark, but here's my interpretation...

Eye morning hair

> I'm mourning her / I'm  here

Doctor me police

> Talk to me please

Bee ring hmm eye death aw ree

> Being/bearing my idea sorry.
>  UPDATE: @Tonkleton's suggestion "Bring my diary" is more likely to be correct.

Thay kiss

> Thanks

Obviously not correct or finished, but it helps if...

> You imagine a person saying it with a swollen tongue/their tongue stuck out.

Comment: Hm, I like where this is going. Could the third line be "Bring my diary"?

Comment: That sounds great! I was stuck on reading "th/aw/ree" as "sorry", but yours makes more sense!

Comment: Swollen tongue? No, but line 3 and 4 are correct. Apparently my friend was very cryptic and random. He mustn't have wanted anyone else to understand.

Comment: The first 2 lines are more cryptic than pronunciation based :P

Comment: Oh and your second guess for line A is correct

Comment: I take it the first line is actually "I *am* here" (a.m. = morning).

Comment: @Gareth Yep ${}$